# How can I add a ChoiceType in every field of a CollectionType in Symfony forms?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to create a form in Symfony. The form needs a collection of **task fields** which are loaded from the database. Every single field should have a dropdown to select a **person** who is supposed to do this task.

What I want to do is to map those two entities together. What I have so far is this:

**createFormType.php**

```
class CreateFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("dateValidFrom", DateTimeType::class)
            ->add("dateValidUntil", DateTimeType::class)
            ->add("generalTasks", CollectionType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            "data_class" => DTOPlan::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

**DTOPlan.php**

```
class DTOPlan
{

    public \DateTimeImmutable $dateValidFrom;

    public \DateTimeImmutable $dateValidUntil;

    public array $tasks;

    public function setGeneralTasks(array $generalTasks): void
    {
        $this->generalTasks = array_fill_keys($generalTasks, null);
    }

...getter and setter
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function newPlan(Request $request)
    {
        $generalTasks = $this->generalTaskRep->findAll();
        $dtoPlan = new DTOPlan();
        $dtoPlan->setGeneralTasks($generalTasks);
        $form=$this->createForm(CreateFormType::class, $dtoPlan);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $this->planRepository->updatePlan($form->getData());
            $this->redirectToRoute("app.plan.show");
        }

        return $this->render("/Plan/plan_create.html.twig", [
            "createForm" => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

The labels are now correct: [Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHRPW.png)

Now I want to insert a dropdown into them for selecting firstName and lastName of **Person**
How can I manage that?

Comment: Custom `ChoiceType` and use it with the `generalTasks` collection by setting the `'entry_type' => YourChoiceType::class` option. This topic is covered in the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

Comment: @emix I am not quite sure if I understand what you are telling me. I also read the Symfony docs about it and I think I grasp it slowly but I cant seem to link it to my problem. I am relatively new to the subject, so my knowledge about Symfony forms is not very advanced.